# c struct with default valuabel?

Tags: c, struct, default

Here I have the following `struct`

```
typedef struct d {
    unsigned int size:  20;
} D;
```

the question is how the default variable `size` be  `10`. Thank your!

Answer (score 2):

In C, types cannot specify default values for variables. Either you need to use C++ with a constructor, or to systematically initialize your variable when you instantiate it.

Answer (score 1):

In C there no such thing as default values or constructors.  You would have to write a function that initializes the `struct` with some default values.  Alternatively you can switch to C++ and make a constructor that would initialize the members of the `struct` with some default values.

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/bitfields.html) for information on what `: 20` in `unsigned int size: 20` mean.

Here is the wikipedia article on [bit fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Bit_fields).

Answer (score 1):

[pratik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/636446/pratik)’s suggestion will work (assuming his use of `typedef` is a typo), but it leaves a global object floating around.  An alternative technique:

```
struct d {
    unsigned int size;
};
/* use only *one* of these next lines */
#define D (struct d){20}    // C99
#define D {20}              // C89
…
struct d foo = D;           // in either case
```

The C99 version has the advantage that it can catch some misuse of the “constructor”, *e.g.*,

```
struct d {
    unsigned int size;
};
#define D99 (struct d){.size = 20}
#define D89 {20}
…
float a[17] = D89;  // compiles, but is that really what you meant? 
float b[17] = D99;  // will not compile
```

Also, you can use the “compound literal” technique to create more complicated constructors, perhaps with arguments.

Answer (score 0):

For making a value of a structure member default u should use something similar to a  constructor's concept in OOP languages..

```
typedef struct d {
    unsigned int size;
} D{20};
```

This way you can specify default values for structure members wenever you create an object of that structure...

Hope it helps.. :)

Comment: Is that `typedef` supposed to be there?

Comment: no its not needed.. i just overlooked it.. just copied his code and pasted it here...

Comment: I mean it’s worse than not needed:  it’s trying to do both `typedef struct d D;` _and_ `struct d D = {20};`—it won’t even compile like this.  See my answer.